# Firebase Firestore query bug if the document uses a large Map field

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

After I upgraded the Firestore android sdk from v20.1.0 to v21.6.0, my Firestore queries are not working as expected.
If I make a simple get() query or a snapshotListener query (realtime) on a single document, the query works once (or twice) then stops working or getting updates (if realtime query), the onEvent() method wouldn't be triggered.

After deep investigation and multiple tests, we (my work team) found that what causes this is that our documents, each, contain a large Map field with at least 5 levels of multi key-value pairs.
Our map field is called "items", when we tried to remove it from the document, the realtime query works perfectly as expected.

P.S: we tried to check the size of the documents, the average was between 6k bytes and 5k bytes, and Firestore allows 1Mb (1M bytes) as a maximum document size.

To reproduce the bug, follow below steps :

1. Add this line into your project gradle file :

   ```
   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
   }
   ```
2. Add those two lines into the module:app gradle file :

   ```
   dependencies {
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.6.0'
      implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
   }
   ```
3. Add this code to create and write a copy of my document into
   firestore :

   ```
   private void createAndWriteDocument() {
       GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
       gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
       gson = gsonBuilder.create();

       FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
               .collection(COLLECTION_ORDERS)
               .document("ZYaJKmQF9n1RknziD1tj")
               .set(gson.fromJson(jsonOrder2, FireStoreOrder.class));
   }

   private final String jsonOrder2 = "{\n" +
           "   \"app_name\":\"Firestore-Sample\",\n" +
           "   \"app_version\":\"1.0.0\",\n" +
           "   \"canceled_at\":\"Sep 4, 2020 15:12:34\",\n" +
           "   \"comments_count\":4,\n" +
           "   \"countryID\":\"fr\",\n" +
           "   \"created_at\":\"Sep 4, 2020 12:21:55\",\n" +
           "   \"currency\":\"EUR\",\n" +
           "   \"delivered_at\":\"Sep 4, 2020 15:11:30\",\n" +
           "   \"delivery_agent_id\":\"1rvlTtfJKNVPVxZ2mp4T2CcI1Fj2\",\n" +
           "   \"delivery_assignment_status\":\"accepted\",\n" +
           "   \"delivery_fee\":5.0,\n" +
           "   \"distance\":3.2547,\n" +
           "   \"hearts_count\":0,\n" +
           "   \"in_progress_at\":\"Sep 4, 2020 15:06:51\",\n" +
           "   \"is_friends\":false,\n" +
           "   \"is_private\":false,\n" +
           "   \"is_public\":true,\n" +
           "   \"is_visible\":true,\n" +
           "   \"items\":{\n" +
           "      \"-MGNqMoKy8YovI11-QUK\":{\n" +
           "         \"category_id\":\"-LlbKEnwkC4KZtJyN691\",\n" +
           "         \"discount_price\":0.0,\n" +
           "         \"extras\":{\n" +
           "            \"-M1-qhcXr8tp5KpnLp9p\":{\n" +
           "               \"max\":10,\n" +
           "               \"name\":\"Chèvre\",\n" +
           "               \"price\":0.6,\n" +
           "               \"quantity\":5,\n" +
           "               \"row\":6\n" +
           "            },\n" +
           "            \"-M1-rHnm7Xzjo7rE73Pk\":{\n" +
           "               \"max\":10,\n" +
           "               \"name\":\"Vache kiri\",\n" +
           "               \"price\":0.6,\n" +
           "               \"quantity\":7,\n" +
           "               \"row\":4\n" +
           "            },\n" +
           "            \"-M1-me-3qKOqWzul67Sr\":{\n" +
           "               \"is_sub_extra\":true,\n" +
           "               \"max\":3,\n" +
           "               \"name\":\"Crispy Tenders\",\n" +
           "               \"price\":0.0,\n" +
           "               \"quantity\":1,\n" +
           "               \"row\":0\n" +
           "            },\n" +
           "            \"-M1-mKvK76SYLJBf3zh-\":{\n" +
           "               \"is_sub_extra\":true,\n" +
           "               \"max\":3,\n" +
           "               \"name\":\"Escalope de Poulet\",\n" +
           "               \"price\":0.0,\n" +
           "               \"quantity\":2,\n" +
           "               \"row\":0\n" +
           "            },\n" +
           "            \"-M1-rNaEFCyHlf9WIOaH\":{\n" +
           "               \"max\":10,\n" +
           "               \"name\":\"Raclette\",\n" +
           "               \"price\":0.6,\n" +
           "               \"quantity\":4,\n" +
           "               \"row\":5\n" +
           "            }\n" +
           "         },\n" +
           "         \"extras_title\":\"Suppléments\",\n" +
           "         \"ingredients\":{\n" +
           "            \"-MEYbO7SlOBFWUVzcvg6\":{\n" +
           "               \"description\":\"Ingredients description\",\n" +
           "               \"name\":\"Cheddar\",\n" +
           "               \"row\":0\n" +
           "            },\n" +
           "            \"-MEYbLvKvqPu3YZPPAjo\":{\n" +
           "               \"description\":\"Ingredients description\",\n" +
           "               \"name\":\"Laitus\",\n" +
           "               \"row\":0\n" +
           "            }\n" +
           "         },\n" +
           "         \"ingredients_title\":\"Ingrédients : Décocher pour enlever\",\n" +
           "         \"itemPrice\":0.0,\n" +
           "         \"main_image\":{\n" +
           "            \"ref\":\"/ZKRBeLgCauXKZ15rfRcuQTY2S1k1/-LlXe_ZbTQytlKujrhLF/products/1582717663739.jpg\",\n" +
           "            \"url\":\"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/urban-food-a9a70.appspot.com/o/ZKRBeLgCauXKZ15rfRcuQTY2S1k1%2F-LlXe_ZbTQytlKujrhLF%2Fproducts%2F1582717663739.jpg?alt\\u003dmedia\\u0026token\\u003d1bbfd8a0-be5a-44c2-8dd9-d5a7dacf2243\"\n" +
           "         },\n" +
           "         \"max_extras\":30,\n" +
           "         \"name\":\"Tacos\",\n" +
           "         \"options\":{\n" +
           "            \"-LlfWYJR_zKtO1l0DjnF\":{\n" +
           "               \"elements\":{\n" +
           "                  \"-LlfWj5L6weXYZUPUoGW\":{\n" +
           "                     \"extras_title\":\"3 Viandes\",\n" +
           "                     \"max\":1,\n" +
           "                     \"max_extras\":3,\n" +
           "                     \"min_extras\":3,\n" +
           "                     \"name\":\"L : Choisir 3 Viandes\",\n" +
           "                     \"price\":9.5,\n" +
           "                     \"row\":0\n" +
           "                  }\n" +
           "               },\n" +
           "               \"name\":\"Taille\",\n" +
           "               \"row\":-1\n" +
           "            },\n" +
           "            \"-LlfX5HY1rzcQpz1p6mG\":{\n" +
           "               \"elements\":{\n" +
           "                  \"-LlfXbVB-QA-utApD3HO\":{\n" +
           "                     \"max\":3,\n" +
           "                     \"name\":\"Barbecue\",\n" +
           "                     \"price\":0.0,\n" +
           "                     \"quantity\":2,\n" +
           "                     \"row\":0\n" +
           "                  },\n" +
           "                  \"-LlfXxF-7RRTZhFwXhyX\":{\n" +
           "                     \"max\":3,\n" +
           "                     \"name\":\"Marocaine\",\n" +
           "                     \"price\":0.0,\n" +
           "                     \"quantity\":2,\n" +
           "                     \"row\":0\n" +
           "                  }\n" +
           "               },\n" +
           "               \"max_quantity\":4,\n" +
           "               \"min_quantity\":1,\n" +
           "               \"name\":\"Sauces\",\n" +
           "               \"row\":3\n" +
           "            },\n" +
           "            \"-LlfWPIAjjgTiqtqEzep\":{\n" +
           "               \"elements\":{\n" +
           "                  \"-LlfWPI9_w1gH1A3HTsB\":{\n" +
           "                     \"name\":\"Tacos\",\n" +
           "                     \"price\":0.0,\n" +
           "                     \"row\":0\n" +
           "                  }\n" +
           "               },\n" +
           "               \"name\":\"Type\",\n" +
           "               \"row\":2\n" +
           "            }\n" +
           "         },\n" +
           "         \"price\":0.0,\n" +
           "         \"product_id\":\"-LlfTFlgrNBdLZRn5xgn\",\n" +
           "         \"quantity\":2,\n" +
           "         \"sub_category_id\":\"-LlbKEnvPMIV3DnSiYlJ\"\n" +
           "      },\n" +
           "      \"-MGNqOGcRfYb-myLgc1d\":{\n" +
           "         \"category_id\":\"-LlkUx5iBSXhKdMYGxTA\",\n" +
           "         \"discount_price\":3.5,\n" +
           "         \"extras\":{\n" +
           "            \"-M2JOJaB_Gsc28GT8wEg\":{\n" +
           "               \"max\":2,\n" +
           "               \"name\":\"Harissa\",\n" +
           "               \"price\":0.0,\n" +
           "               \"quantity\":1,\n" +
           "               \"row\":2\n" +
           "            }\n" +
           "         },\n" +
           "         \"extras_title\":\"Sauces\",\n" +
           "         \"itemPrice\":0.0,\n" +
           "         \"main_image\":{\n" +
           "            \"ref\":\"/ZKRBeLgCauXKZ15rfRcuQTY2S1k1/-LlXe_ZbTQytlKujrhLF/products/1582809519364.jpg\",\n" +
           "            \"url\":\"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/urban-food-a9a70.appspot.com/o/ZKRBeLgCauXKZ15rfRcuQTY2S1k1%2F-LlXe_ZbTQytlKujrhLF%2Fproducts%2F1582809519364.jpg?alt\\u003dmedia\\u0026token\\u003dabc457cb-2462-44be-886a-af83db3cb501\"\n" +
           "         },\n" +
           "         \"max_extras\":2,\n" +
           "         \"name\":\"Oignons frites\",\n" +
           "         \"options\":{\n" +
           "            \"-M15mpsXwAzsDRlLDHJI\":{\n" +
           "               \"elements\":{\n" +
           "                  \"-M15mpsXwAzsDRlLDHJG\":{\n" +
           "                     \"name\":\"Cheddar\",\n" +
           "                     \"price\":0.0,\n" +
           "                     \"row\":0\n" +
           "                  }\n" +
           "               },\n" +
           "               \"name\":\"Au choix :\",\n" +
           "               \"row\":-1\n" +
           "            }\n" +
           "         },\n" +
           "         \"price\":3.5,\n" +
           "         \"product_id\":\"-M15mV_4Ui2B90GlzsaR\",\n" +
           "         \"quantity\":1,\n" +
           "         \"sub_category_id\":\"-LlkUx5h8rXECP8L_hjQ\"\n" +
           "      },\n" +
           "      \"-MGNqOxoHFGoigUXao96\":{\n" +
           "         \"category_id\":\"-LlkUx5iBSXhKdMYGxTA\",\n" +
           "         \"discount_price\":3.5,\n" +
           "         \"extras\":{\n" +
           "            \"-M2JOmBf1oN1BmUUHeiY\":{\n" +
           "               \"name\":\"Biggy burger\",\n" +
           "               \"price\":0.0,\n" +
           "               \"quantity\":1,\n" +
           "               \"row\":0\n" +
           "            }\n" +
           "         },\n" +
           "         \"itemPrice\":0.0,\n" +
           "         \"main_image\":{\n" +
           "            \"ref\":\"/ZKRBeLgCauXKZ15rfRcuQTY2S1k1/-LlXe_ZbTQytlKujrhLF/products/1582809369789.jpg\",\n" +
           "            \"url\":\"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/urban-food-a9a70.appspot.com/o/ZKRBeLgCauXKZ15rfRcuQTY2S1k1%2F-LlXe_ZbTQytlKujrhLF%2Fproducts%2F1582809369789.jpg?alt\\u003dmedia\\u0026token\\u003d705593e0-e403-4931-b040-5b2261cb96e5\"\n" +
           "         },\n" +
           "         \"name\":\"Bacon frites\",\n" +
           "         \"options\":{\n" +
           "            \"-M15lyQyHs1GujtZxMtS\":{\n" +
           "               \"elements\":{\n" +
           "                  \"-M15lyQxrRFaLAWGaa3i\":{\n" +
           "                     \"name\":\"Sauce fromagère\",\n" +
           "                     \"price\":0.0,\n" +
           "                     \"row\":0\n" +
           "                  }\n" +
           "               },\n" +
           "               \"name\":\"Au choix :\",\n" +
           "               \"row\":-1\n" +
           "            }\n" +
           "         },\n" +
           "         \"price\":3.5,\n" +
           "         \"product_id\":\"-M15lqmhF16ZOLqebPzs\",\n" +
           "         \"quantity\":1,\n" +
           "         \"sub_category_id\":\"-LlkUx5h8rXECP8L_hjQ\"\n" +
           "      }\n" +
           "   },\n" +
           "   \"itemsCount\":0,\n" +
           "   \"level_one_zone_id\":\"Île-de-France\",\n" +
           "   \"level_two_zone_id\":\"Paris\",\n" +
           "   \"order_id\":\"ZYaJKmQF9n1RknziD1tj\",\n" +
           "   \"order_number\":31,\n" +
           "   \"order_type\":\"delivery\",\n" +
           "   \"paid\":false,\n" +
           "   \"paid_with_loyalty\":0.0,\n" +
           "   \"picked_at\":\"Sep 4, 2020 15:12:46\",\n" +
           "   \"platform\":\"android\",\n" +
           "   \"processedAt\":{\n" +
           "      \"nanoseconds\":994000000,\n" +
           "      \"seconds\":1599228406\n" +
           "   },\n" +
           "   \"restaurant_photo\":\"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/menutium-319d0.appspot.com/o/LHx3fTdtoaRlrAHSjznJSaPz9rP2%2F-MEYUb7iepk3pLwUyWX3%2Fprofile%2F1597250393877.jpg?alt\\u003dmedia\\u0026token\\u003dcbccd3fe-91fd-4397-ab34-79f5f241def2\",\n" +
           "   \"status\":\"picked\",\n" +
           "   \"store_id\":\"-MEYUb7iepk3pLwUyWX3\",\n" +
           "   \"store_name\":\"La Fourchette\",\n" +
           "   \"total_price\":50.2,\n" +
           "   \"updated_at\":\"Sep 7, 2020 18:54:02\",\n" +
           "   \"user_address\":\"166 Quai de Stalingrad, 92130 Issy-les-Moulineaux, France\\nIssy-les-Moulineaux\",\n" +
           "   \"user_coordinates\":\"48.8256954,2.2579879\",\n" +
           "   \"user_name\":\"Mo Salah\",\n" +
           "   \"user_phone\":\"+21650001002\",\n" +
           "   \"user_photo\":\"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/menutium-319d0.appspot.com/o/2Bz8euUmPgMqc4Z7QZWJjLfsgV72%2Fphoto_profile?alt\\u003dmedia\\u0026token\\u003df5dcee5b-fdda-45bd-9ec3-982cfe7832bd\",\n" +
           "   \"user_uid\":\"2Bz8euUmPgMqc4Z7QZWJjLfsgV72\",\n" +
           "   \"validated_at\":\"Sep 4, 2020 15:12:42\",\n" +
           "   \"validatedBy\":{\n" +
           "      \"name\":\"Urban-Admin\",\n" +
           "      \"id\":\"admin\"\n" +
           "   }\n" +
           "}";
   ```
4. Start a realtime query on this document :

   ```
           FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                   .collection("orders")
                   .document("ZYaJKmQF9n1RknziD1tj")
                   .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value,
                                           @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                           Log.d("testing", "onEvent triggered");
                           if (error != null) {
                               Log.i("testing", "test error : "+ error.getMessage());
                           }
                       }
                   });
   ```

We created two Android projects (Java code), put them into public Github repos so that anyone could reproduce the issue we are facing.

Everything is detailed into the Readme repos.

[First Project repository](https://github.com/MahmoudiOussama/firestore-sample)

[Second Project repository with minimal code](https://github.com/MahmoudiOussama/firestore-minimal-implementation)

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the relevant code must be copied into the question - please edit the question to do so.  Do not link to external resources, as those are not guaranteed to have the same lifetime as this question, and will not be helpful to others in the future.

Comment: Doug comment is valid, on the other hand if you are sure this is a bug please raise this issue on https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs

Comment: Thank you all for commenting. I did send a bug report on firebase troubleshooter. I am thinking of what code should i set in my question, cause stackoverflow acccepts 30k characters only :'(

Comment: It's expected that you show the complete, minimal code that reproduces the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DougStevenson, Sir, please consider taking seriously this issue, we have been using the Firebase Firestore for more than a year now, we never faced such bugs, it was always fast, and performant. We had to downgrade to v20.1.0 so that our App works fine.
What if the minimal code to reproduce an issue exceeds the maximum allowed characters in Stackoverflow ? we just close the issue ? It is obvious that creating a free public repository in Github, with the minimal code that reproduces the problem is the best practice as far as i know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before i create this question, i created an issue within the official firebase-android-sdk repository.
After five days, someone from the Firebase team answered me, they did found a bug in the Firestore sdk, fixed it, but still didn't released it, so he recommended to downgrade to older version than 21.5.0 to avoid the bug as a temporary workaround.
Github issue link [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1971)